# Free Abelian Group with Relation $\sum b_i = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

What is the name of a free abelian group $G$ with the relation $\sum b_i = 0$, where $b_i$ is the basis of $G$? And is there any good introductory literature on these objects?

Comment: Why do you think there is a standard name? It's just the  free abelian group of rank $n-1$.

Comment: I think that answers the question then.  I'm not a group theorist, but I've started studying objects that have this group structure and didn't know how to find out more about it.

Comment: Don't the $b_i$ need to be linearly independent to form a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$ with basis $b_1,\dots,b_n$, then $G$ mod the relation $\sum b_i = 0$ is a free abelian group of rank $n-1$.